# Spiff not working properly when I have code on top of yml

Tags: erb, templating

I have 3 yml file 0.yml, 1.yml and 2.yml.

Their contents are the following.

**0.yml**

```
name: (( merge ))
director_uuid: (( merge ))
foo1: (( merge ))
```

**1.yml**

```
<%
  director_uuid = `bosh status --uuid 2>/dev/null`.strip
%>
---
name: service-fabrik
director_uuid: <%= director_uuid %>
foo1: (( merge ))
```

**2.yml**

```
foo1: bar1
```

If I do spiff merge 0.yml 1.yml 2.yml > 3.yml then 3.yml looks like this.

```
foo1: bar1
```

I want it to be like the following :

```
name: service-fabrik
director_uuid: jfheifefefif
foo1: bar1
```

But it does not work. If I remove the code part from 1.yml

```
<%
  director_uuid = `bosh status --uuid 2>/dev/null`.strip
%>
```

Then it works normally. But I want it. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing two kinds of templating tools. `0.yml` is indeed in the [spiff](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff) format, but `1.yml` is using [ERB](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.0/lang_template_erb.html) and `spiff`. `spiff` doesn't know how to handle ERB, that's why it's not working for you. To fix this, you must choose one template style (`spiff` or `ERB`), convert the all files to the correct format, and use the respectful engine to generate your files. I would suggest `ERB` over `spiff` as it's much better documented and powerful.